# How do I line break an element with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

**What I need**

Execute Nokogiri query, add a line break so when data is outputted its not bunched up.

```
data = doc.css('div#specifications div#spec-area ul.product-spec')[0].text
```

**I tried this**

```
data = doc.css('div#specifications div#spec-area ul.product-spec')[0].css('li').each{ |li| li.replace '\n' }.text
```

**My Full Code**

```
require 'Nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'spreadsheet'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_TAICHI_21/#specifications"))

#Grab our product specifications - we only need the text not HTML
data = doc.css('div#specifications div#spec-area ul.product-spec')[0].text 

#Create the Spreadsheet
Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new

sheet1 = book.create_worksheet
sheet1.name = 'My First Worksheet'

#Output our data  to the Spreadsheet
sheet1[0,0] = data
book.write 'C:/Users/Barry/Desktop/output.xls'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to replace the list elements, you just want to map them to their texts and then join them together separated by newlines.

If you grab the elements with this:

```
data = doc.css('div#specifications div#spec-area ul.product-spec li')
```

Then you can get a list of all the list elements separated by linebreaks using [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and [`join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-join), like this:

```
lines = data.map(&:text).join("\n")
```

(From the comments) I've never used ruby spreadsheet before, but this should allow you to input the data:

```
data = doc.css('div#specifications div#spec-area ul.product-spec li')
data.each_with_index { |line, i| sheet1[i,0] = line.text }
```

Hope that helps.

p.s. "nokogiri" in `require "nokogiri"` should be all lowercase.

Comment: That worked nicely however...the output doesn't appear as expected. I assumed each \n would add the table row by row to the spreadsheet. Any ideas?

Comment: Updated my answer. But really, you should only ask one thing per question.

Comment: Ok will post as new question! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To add a newline after each li:

```
ul = doc.at('div#specifications div#spec-area ul.product-spec')
ul.search('li').each{|li| li.after "\n"}
puts ul.text
```